# Selecting a div in jQuery & appending to the DOM

Tags: jquery

```
        var activeMsg=[];       // Active Users
        var noactiveMsg=[];     // Non-Active Users with a Pending Message
        var noactiveNomsg=[];       // Non-Active Users without a Pending Message

        $('div.chatmember').each(function() {
            currentMember=$(this);

            if($(this).children().children('div').hasClass('chatactivestatus_online')) {
                alert('online');
                activeMsg.push(currentMember);
            }
            if($(this).children().children('div').hasClass('chatactivestatus_offline')) {
                alert('offline');
                noactiveMsg.push(currentMember);
            }               
        });

        $.each(noactiveMsg, function(i, e){
             $('#chatCenterMembers').append(e.html());
         })
```

The above code is quering DOM structure that looks like this:

```
 <div id="chatCenterMembers">
   <div class="chatmember">
      <a class="ststusTitle">
         <div class="chatactivestatus_online"></div>
```

it all works except for `currentMember=$(this);`
I believe this should hold `<div class="chatmember">`

when I do the append at the end of the code above it doesn't add `<div class="chatmember">` back into the dom. It adds its children elements only.

Comment: How do you mean "refer to the `<div id="adam">` directly"? What are it's children?

Comment: I'm looping on $('div.chatmember').each(function() {  - I want to be able refer to <div id="adam" class="chatmember"> in the $(this) but when I append the object back into the DOM it appends its children not the div id=adam itself

Comment: Can you show us some more code? Specifically some more of the HTML and JS? The snippets you have included aren't especially useful. You're talking about appending back into the DOM, but you don't show us that code. It would be kinda helpful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you issue is this line here:

```
$('#chatCenterMembers').append(e.html());
```

and more specifically: `e.html()`

Accourding to the jQuery spec for [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements.

which means that `.html()` returns the child contents of the selection, not the selection itself.

What you want to do, is just use `.append()`, this will append the entire selected div and not just it's children

Comment: hay I agree with you... but I'm struggling to get just .append() to append anything... I've tried $('#chatCenterMembers').append(); and remove the i,e from the function but this doesn't append anything... I've also tried $('#chatCenterMembers').e.append(); but this doesn't seem to work... do you have any advise on how to append the array of  objects into the DOM... cheers

Comment: `$('#chatCenterMembers').append(e)` should work. You are selecting the `chatCenterMemmbers`, then appending the value `e`. Have a read of the jQuery documentation on `append()`, it's very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just raced ahead a little bit. Using your js, `$(this)` will refer to your inner div. `$(this).parent()` will refer to the outer one.

---

some html

```
<div id="chatCenterMembers">
   <div id="adam" class="chatmember">
       hello!
    </div>
</div>
```

---

the js

```
$(function(){
    $("div.chatmember").each(function(){

        // current member is now div#adam
        var currentMember = $(this);

        currentMember.css('border', '5px solid blue');

        // parent of currentMember references div#chatCenterMembers
        currentMember.parent().css('border', '5px solid red');

    });
});
```

[see it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Ahj/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('div.chatmember').each(function(domEle){
    currentMember=$(domEle);
```